# Nginx Proxy Pass custom port to 443 to docker container(AWS,Ubuntu)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, proxy, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I setup with docker environment with customer port(444) because then I don't want to stop normal 443 local Nginx.

this is my docker-composer.yml

```
    version: '3.8'
    services:
      web:
        container_name: custom_web
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./.docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
          - ./.docker/certs:/mycert
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
          - "444:443"
        .....
```

the normal local environment I try to proxy pass to 443 to 444.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name exmple.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name exmple.com;;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:444;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

But after nginx server restart and run I can show network tab all file load but show error

> "400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
> nginx/1.19.2"

What is the best way to resolve that error...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:444;` to `proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:444;`